# Request accesstoken fails with raison: parameter code is missing, but the attributeList has an attribute named code?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I am troubleshooting my OAuth2.0 flow between my GAE application and our Connections4 test environment. With the tracing enabled on the Connections server, I see these lines:

```
{_status: 1 _attributeList: {{name: request_type type: urn:ibm:names:oauth:request values: [access_token]},{name: client_id type: urn:ibm:names:oauth:param values: [socialdms4g]},{name: callback_uri type: urn:ibm:names:query:param values: [https://eog-fire-ice.appspot.com/socialdms]},{name: client_id type: urn:ibm:names:query:param values: [socialdms4g]},{name: code type: urn:ibm:names:query:param values: [Pb2JtuOb1UkgPyV6aT1LflZ12B6kL1]},{name: client_secret type: urn:ibm:names:query:param values: [REMOVED]},{name: grant_type type: urn:ibm:names:query:param values: [authorization_code]}} _cause: com.ibm.oauth.core.api.error.oauth20.OAuth20MissingParameterException: A required runtime parameter was missing: code}
[12-12-12 16:15:08:680 CET] 000000e8 CachedDBToken 3   processing exception with OAuthResult: invalid_request
[12-12-12 16:15:08:680 CET] 000000e8 CachedDBToken <  handleResultException Exit
                             {_status: 1 _attributeList: {{name: request_type type: urn:ibm:names:oauth:request values: [access_token]},{name: client_id type: urn:ibm:names:oauth:param values: [socialdms4g]},{name: callback_uri type: urn:ibm:names:query:param values: [https://eog-fire-ice.appspot.com/socialdms]},{name: client_id type: urn:ibm:names:query:param values: [socialdms4g]},{name: code type: urn:ibm:names:query:param values: [Pb2JtuOb1UkgPyV6aT1LflZ12B6kL1]},{name: client_secret type: urn:ibm:names:query:param values: [REMOVED]},{name: grant_type type: urn:ibm:names:query:param values: [authorization_code]}} _cause: com.ibm.oauth.core.api.error.oauth20.OAuth20MissingParameterException: A required runtime parameter was missing: code}
[12-12-12 16:15:08:680 CET] 000000e8 OAuth20Endpoi <  processTokenRequest Exit
```

The url that is used to invoke this sequence contains a code (and all other) parameter(s).

What could be the cause of this and even better, how can I fix this ?

Comment: I'm an IBM developer working on an oAuth application and having the same problem with the IBM connections test server (I've confirmed it's a problem on their end), I'm talking to the L3 team right now and I'll let you know what response I get. Alternately if you found a solution/workaround I'd be very happy to hear it.

Comment: @redball I have share the code that works for us today

Answer (score 0):

At least we can easily see what the problem is :)
com.ibm.oauth.core.api.error.oauth20.OAuth20MissingParameterException: A required runtime parameter was missing: code

Code is one of the parameters that should be sent in the [request to get the access token](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.1.3).  Searching the src code of the SDK it looks like this should be sent all the time in OAuth2Handler.getAccessTokenForAuthorizedUser().  Is that being called?

Answer (score 0):

@redball

This is what we have working today

```
redirectURL = "/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/authorize?response_type=code&_oauth_client_auto_authorize=true&client_id="+AppId+"&callback_uri="+CallbackUrl;
```

Where AppId and CallBackUrl are specific for your application.

In the doGet of your callBackUrl Servlet, use this helper class

```
com.ibm.sbt.security.authentication.oauth.consumer.OAuth2Handler
```

We have done it like this

```
OAuth2Handler oAuth2Handler = new OAuth2Handler();
logger.warning("WARNING Always trusting SSL certificate !!");
oAuth2Handler.setForceTrustSSLCertificate(true);
logger.fine("getting accesstoken...");
oAuth2Handler.setClient_uri(CallbackUrl);

oAuth2Handler.setConsumerKey(AppId);
oAuth2Handler.setAuthorization_code(code);
oAuth2Handler.setConsumerSecret(AppSecret);
oAuth2Handler.setAccessTokenURL(AccessTokenUrl);

logger.fine("getting token using GET...");
oAuth2Handler.getAccessTokenForAuthorizedUser();
String accessToken = oAuth2Handler.getAccessToken();
String expiresIn = oAuth2Handler.getExpiresIn()
String refreshToken = oAuth2Handler.getRefreshToken();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been incredibly helpful

Comment: but of course now I'm getting a different error, it looks like some param isn't being set for the request and it's causing an internal server error, is that the full source code for the token request?

Comment: Yes, all you need from the redirectURL is de querystring param : code. Pass this to the oAuth2Handler.

Of course this code is not executable as is. But check the OAuth playground in greenhouse...